# Validation rule to compare the queue name with a Custom object field

Tags: validation, queue

I need to create a validation rule to compare the text field value (which is input type) with the Queue list present in my org and if the Text field value is not present the into the Queue List then need to give error message.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I  don't think it will be possible using validation rule. You need to use Trigger or  Hierarchical custom setting approach.

Comment: Can we access the queues name in validation rule using Vlookup or anything else?

Comment: If you want to use CS then you can directly access them.

Comment: Can you share the number of Queues that are present in your system at this point?

Comment: around 15 queues are present in my org as of now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you strictly want to NOT use code.  Then the option I can think of is to have a copy of Queue Names in Custom settings (hierarchical).  Your validation rules can access custom settings and hence you can validate.

Just make sure your Queues and Custom settings are always in sync if you prefer this approach.

[image]

Comment: So do I need to use VLookup in validation rule for getting the value from  Custom settings?

Comment: No. You can treat them as normal text fields only.  If you click on Insert Field in Validation formula,  you can see your custom settings as $Setup.Custom_Settings__c

Comment: Added image to the answer